# Crystal Report Not Showing Properly in Visual studio 2008

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I develop some Crystal Reports for my various application in visual studio,
but today i am not able to see report properly.. in run time as well in Source code.
its shows as below image, i think may be some problem in my Visual studio, so i re install it.
but still facing problem.
kindly guide me which point i missed..

how to increase margin size in this

Note: i am using Visual studio 2008  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution , I just Right Click On my report. Go to, Page Setup > Check 'No Printer', and increase the Horizontal Page Size.  its Done